# How to download APK file from Google Play programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to download a few applications from Google Play to my phone. I try follow answer [Download App from Google Play programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931590/download-app-from-google-play-programatically/16944454#16944454), but have an exceptions: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>` or `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)`. And it problem is library. Also I try use [android-market-api](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/), but also have exception because ClientLogin is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official API to download APKs programmatically. But to address your exception, it seems like you're using Apache HTTP Client and running your app on a device with Android Marshmallow (6.0) or above.

Apache HTTP Client [has been removed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) as of Marshmallow. [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) can be used instead.